# Horizontal scroll bar appearing in all mobile browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple website that creates a horizontal scrollbar in the following:

**Android:**

Chrome

Firefox

Opera Mini

*Not in Android Default browser but the site looks broken*

**iOS:**

Safari

---

It's really no big deal but I'm comparing my website to the full desktop site of `http://google.com` and Google's website doesn't get the same problem as mine.

I am still pretty new at CSS and HTML and I feel like I'm breaking some really simple rule I don't know about that is creating this problem. Any ideas on how to fix this?

If you would like to test it. Go to http://natio.in

Answer (score 1):

The horizontal scroll bar is appearing because you have fixed width's set on elements, that when the site is viewed on a mobile browser, the width of those elements is set wider than that of the viewport width.  If you use a percent for widths, your webpage will be able to adjust accordingly.

Comment: Alright, I'm okay with it having the scroll bar then, but I don't get why it creates a weird effect with the black bar going across. Screenshot here: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7D4SZeRrwSGcHU3Y0VELVVnSVE You can see that the black bar doesn't go all the way across.

Comment: It can also be caused by elements that are 100% width that also have left or right padding (which forces the element to be wider than 100%). To fix this, `box-sizing` needs to be set to `border-box`.

Answer (score 0):

well, you can include `overflow-x: hidden;` in the styles for your body tag, but if there is content outside the width of the phone, you wont be able to get to it. Or you could crate a responsive layout with media queries.

Comment: Added it in my body, but I'm still getting the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I put it back now, but I took it off because it didn't work.

Comment: Well, then I'm not sure. I'm testing it on my phone, and I'm getting the same problem.